# Simple registering of Tortoise ORM models with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I have a FastAPI app with an existing MySQL database, and I'm trying to use Tortoise ORM.
The (simplified) main FastAPI file looks like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise

# Register FastAPI main app
app = FastAPI(title="my_app")


# Database
DATABASE_URL = "mysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(
    os.environ["MYSQL_USER"],
    os.environ["MYSQL_PASSWORD"],
    os.environ.get("MYSQL_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
    os.environ.get("MYSQL_PORT", "3306"),
    os.environ.get("MYSQL_DB", "my_db"),
)

# Register Tortoise ORM with DB
register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=DATABASE_URL,
    modules={"models": ["models"]},
    generate_schemas=False,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)


# Test SQL query
from models import Store
print(Store.get(api_key="api_key"))
```

...and a models.py file, at same base directory level, looking like this:

```
from tortoise import fields
from tortoise.models import Model


class Store(Model):
    api_key = fields.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        table = "stores"
```

However, I get an error from Tortoise ORM:

```
  File ".../site-packages/tortoise/models.py", line 265, in db
    raise ConfigurationError("No DB associated to model")
tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: No DB associated to model
```

Any idea why?

I'm following the doc (https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib/fastapi.html) but the path/syntax for "modules that should be discovered for models" is not very clear to me. I also tried with registering the models with `pydantic_model_creator`, though not clear in the doc why you need that (https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/fastapi.html#example-fastapi).
I would prefer not to use the config.json full config file loaded by `register_tortoise`, it seems optional according to the doc.

Comment: From where are you running the app? It can be because you start it on a level above the `app.py` file, thus expecting the `models.py` file one level above. If you have `app/main.py` and `app/models.py`, then the path is `app.models`

Comment: I'm not using any `app.py` file, FastAPI app is instanciated in `main.py` as `app`, and `models.py` file is at same level as `main.py`.

Comment: Then change `app.py` with `main.py`. When you run the command, where is the terminal pointing at? At the same level of `main.py` or at the level above?

Comment: Regarding the command run in the terminal, it's run at same level as `main.py` and `models.py`. Regarding `main.py`, I don't understand what you mean, since everything is at the same level.

Comment: 1) That's odd. Does the schema exist in you database? 2) Since I did not know how your main file is called, I gave it the name `app.py`, but since you pointed out that it `main.py` I simply changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from the async nature of FastAPI and Tortoise ORM.
We have to wait for FastAPI to load and Tortoise to register the models.

So we can successfully do an async request that waits for FastAPI to load, and Tortoise ORM to request, like this:

```
# Test SQL query
from models import Store

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    print(await Store.get(api_key="api_key"))
```

Comment: is this the way to `startup` the database connection? by making a request? how do we `shutdown`?

Comment: No, you have to register Tortoise before. This is just to wait for startup before making the request.

Comment: issue am having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741715/issues-with-initializing-tortoise-orm-with-fastapi

Answer (score 1):

In our case, one of the ASGI middleware (which did not support asgi lifespan events) was raising an error during startup which prevented the ASGI lifespan events (namely `startup`) from firing and did not register the models. We ended up patching the middleware to be fired only for `scope['type']` == `'http'`.

The [ASGI spec](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specs/lifespan.html#scope) states that the server must continue even after startup errors.

> If an exception is raised when calling the application callable with a lifespan.startup message or a scope with type lifespan, the server must continue but not send any lifespan events.

However tortoise ORM `register_tortoise` function relies on the lifespan event `startup` to register models. So I think the lifespan mode on uvicorn should be `on` instead of the default `auto`. This way your server process will terminate rather than serving a misconfigured app.

```
uvicorn.run("start_server:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, log_level="info", lifespan='on')
```