# issues with initializing tortoise orm with fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, tortoise-orm

i am having issue with tortoise orm and fastapi

i have the following code from `app.py`; i have skipped some lines to make this concise

`app.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from app.models import User_Pydantic, UserIn_Pydantic, Users
from app.utils import cryptoUtil
from app.auth import auth as auth_router
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import HTTPNotFoundError, register_tortoise


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/users", response_model=User_Pydantic)
async def create_user(user: UserIn_Pydantic):
    user.password = cryptoUtil.hash_password(user.password)
    user_obj = Users(email=user.email, password=user.password, fullname=user.fullname, status=user.status)
    await user_obj.save()

    return await User_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(user_obj)




register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=config.DATABASE_URL,
    modules={"models": ["app.models"]},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)


app.include_router(auth_router.router, tags=["Auth"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

this works fine and able to create users

but now i am trying to do the same from another file

`auth.py`

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
from app.auth import crud
from app.utils import cryptoUtil
from app.models import User_Pydantic, UserIn_Pydantic, Users


router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/auth/register", response_model=User_Pydantic)
async def register(user: UserIn_Pydantic):
    result = await crud.find_exist_user(user.email)
    
    if result:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="user already exists!")
    
    user.password = cryptoUtil.hash_password(user.password)
    user_obj = Users(email=user.email, password=user.password, fullname=user.fullname, status=user.status)
    await user_obj.save()

    return await User_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(user_obj)
```

but this does not work and i get this in 404 error response

```
{
  "detail": "Object does not exist"
}
```

i think the issue am having is that the `from_tortoise_orm(user_obj)` in

```
return await User_Pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(user_obj)
```

is not able to work in `auth.py` file because for some reason i cant run it outside of `app.py` file which is where tortoise is initialized

what do i do to fix this?
part of the issue am having is how to be able to call tortoise initialization from outside `app.py` where `register_tortoise` exists

> **UPDATES:**

folder structure

```
├── app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── config.py
│   │
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── auth.py
│   │   ├── crud.py
│   │      
│   └── utils
│       ├── cryptoUtil.py
│
```

Comment: If you don't show also the folder structure one assumes that everything is in the same folder (which I guess is not). Also, I think you are missing Tortoise.init_models(models_list, "models") before the register_tortoise

Comment: i added folder structure...i do not have this `Tortoise.init_models(models_list, "models")` anywhere in my code...where do i add this? and what is it's use?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, you need to insert

```
Tortoise.init_models(models_list, "models")
```

before the following line

```
register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=config.DATABASE_URL,
    modules={"models": ["app.models"]},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)
```

Of course you'll have to change the "models" folder and name according to your configuration.

At the beginning it was also a problem for me as well, but the following github issue solved the problem

https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/issues/444

Also the docs provide the explanation

[https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=early+init](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=early%20init)

**UPDATE**

```
Tortoise.init_models(models_list, "models")
```

models_list is the list (strings) of paths of the models that are to be considered. In your case, it'll be `app.models`.

The idea is to initialize and start preparing the models, before connecting to the database. This is a step required in order to make relations available in the pydantic models.

Here the API docs

https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html?highlight=init#tortoise.Tortoise.init_models

Comment: you mind explaining what this line `Tortoise.init_models(models_list, "models")` does? also i get this error when i added it to `app.py` file, here is the error i get `File "/usr/src/app/app/app.py", line 73, in <module> Tortoise.init_models(models_list, "models") NameError: name 'models_list' is not defined`

Comment: even after reading this https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#tortoise.Tortoise.init_models i still have no clue what the 2 parameters are..the second i assume it is name of the models file so for me it will be `models` but first parameter is a mystery

Comment: I updated the answer. Thought you received the notification

Comment: didnt get the notification...so it should be this? `Tortoise.init_models(["app.models"], "models")`

Comment: Yes. It initializes the Tortoise models that are declared within "app.models" under the common name "models". Then, when initializing Tortoise, these models will be used by the orm. It should work, as I haven't tested your code it's not super easy to say

Comment: still does not work..do i need to add `Tortoise.init_models(["app.models"], "models")` to `auth.py` file? because remember it is same exact code to create user in `app.py` but the one in `auth.py` does not work...and same code...still getting the error message ` "detail": "Object does not exist"`

Comment: No, it's enough to insert Tortoise.init_models(["app.models"], "models") before registering tortoise. Provide your error trace in the question. The error you get is generic and is also returned to the client, without revealing important information

Comment: trace error `TRACE:uvicorn.asgi:10.10.19.7:45086 - ASGI [4] Completed
TRACE:    10.10.19.7:45086 - Connection lost
TRACE:uvicorn.error:10.10.19.7:45086 - Connection lost`

Comment: `TRACE:    10.10.19.7:45692 - ASGI [10] Completed
TRACE:uvicorn.asgi:10.10.19.7:45692 - ASGI [10] Completed
TRACE:    10.10.19.7:45692 - Connection lost
TRACE:uvicorn.error:10.10.19.7:45692 - Connection lost`

Comment: I have no clue what is this. Can you contextualize it in your answer and provide the full error trace? From what is written, the only thing I can say is that your server went down, but don't know which one

Comment: that is from enable trace error logging for uvicorn, how do i get the full trace error you want? also that is what is returned when i make the POST request having issues from `auth.py`

Comment: What you see on the terminal. That is the result of the python command

Comment: app is dockerized and i have enabled trace logging from uvicorn and i just sent you what error i get in terminal...it returns that everytime that POSt request fails together with the generic error message i sent originally...so nothing is getting shown much

Comment: Then don't dockerize it or enter via ssh and run manually the command. Otherwise I can't help